# malloc and pointer in a struct

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following C code:

```
typedef struct DListNode_ {
    void    *data;
    struct DListNode_ *prev;
    struct DListNode_ *next;
} DListNode;


typedef struct DList_ {
    int size;
    DListNode  *tail;
    DListNode  *head;
} DList;

void insert(DList * list, DListNode * element, int data) {
    DListNode * new_element = (DListNode *)malloc(sizeof(DListNode));
    new_element->data = &data;
    if (list->head==NULL) {
        list->head=list->tail=new_element;
        list->size++;
        return;
    }
    if(element == NULL) {
        // handle size==0?
        new_element->next=list->head;
        list->head->prev=new_element;
        list->head=new_element;
        list->size++;
    } else {
        printf("Not yet implemented!\n");
    }
}

void printNodes(DList *list) {
    DListNode * pointer = list->head;
    if (pointer!=NULL) {
        int v= *((int*)pointer->data);
        printf("Node has value: %d\n", v);
        while (pointer->next != NULL) {
            v = *((int*)pointer->data);
            printf("Node has value: %d\n", v);
            pointer=pointer->next;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    int e0 = 23;
    int e1 = 7;
    int e2 = 11;
    DList *list = (DList *)malloc(sizeof(DList));
    initList(list);
    assert(count(list)==0);
    insert(list, NULL, e0);
    assert(count(list)==1);

    insert(list,NULL, e1);
    assert(count(list)==2);

    insert(list,NULL, e2);
    assert(count(list)==3);
    printNodes(list);

    return 0;
}
```

I have a few problems:

1. does **DListNode * new_element = (DListNode *)malloc(sizeof(DListNode));** also allocate space for the, data, prev, next pointer or do I manually need to call malloc on each of those pointers?
2. When I print the content of the data pointer in each node they all have the value **3** even though I insert 23, 7 and 11 and set the data pointer to the address of the int: **   new_element->data = &data;**.

(Introductionary textbooks on C have been ordered)

EDIT:

insert now takes a void pointer to the data:

```
// Insert data as the new head
void insert(DList *list, DListNode *element, void *data) {
    DListNode *new_element = malloc(sizeof(DListNode));
    new_element->data = data;
    if (list->head==NULL) {
        list->head=list->tail=new_element;
        list->size++;
        return;
    }
    if(element == NULL) {
        new_element->next=list->head;
        list->head->prev=new_element;
        list->head=new_element;
        list->size++;
    } else {
        printf("Not yet implemented!\n");
    }
}
```

In main I do:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int i0=7;
    int *ip0 = malloc(sizeof(int));
    ip0 = &i0;

    int i1=8;
    int *ip1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
    ip1 = &i1;

    int *ip2 = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int i2=44;
    ip2 = &i2;

    DList *list = malloc(sizeof(DList));
    initList(list);
    // create some nodes
    assert(count(list)==0);
    insert(list, NULL, ip0);
    assert(count(list)==1);

    insert(list,NULL, ip1);
    assert(count(list)==2);

    insert(list,NULL, ip2);
    assert(count(list)==3);
    printNodes(list);

    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
Node has value: 44
Node has value: 44
Node has value: 8
```

but it should be:

```
Node has value: 44
Node has value: 8
Node has value: 7
```

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.

Comment: A `DListNode_ ` is nothing more than the sum of its fields. There is nothing to allocate _other_ than than the pointers you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

1. `malloc(sizeof(DListNode))` allocates space for exactly one `DListNode`, which by definition consists of a `void*` and two `DListNode` pointers. It does not initialize those pointers, though.
2. You're assigning the address of the `data` argument to `insert`. That's a pointer to a temporary which is invalidated once `insert` returns. The behavior of the program is undefined. The easy solution is to just replace `void *data` by `int data`.

Comment: .. and initializing them may not require a call to `malloc`.  In fact, for normal linked-list behaviour, you probably *won't* `malloc` them.

Comment: @CarlNorum: I'm not sure what you mean. Whenever (or: the few times that) I implemented linked lists in C, I `malloc`'d every node, separately, although that's not required in every situation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure (though he can correct me if I'm wrong) that the OP is asking if he needs to call `malloc` three more times after his program's current call to initialize the pointers in his list structure.  I'm just saying that he probably doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to manually set those pointers to where they point with malloc.  Without it, they will point to a space that isn't of size DListNode.
2. Don't make the data a pointer.  Just make the data an int (it gets auto allocated) and then just set data = data (the data that is passed into insert).

Comment: `malloc` is probably *not* necessary for normal list semantics.  Just point them at preexisting nodes (or to NULL if there aren't any).

Comment: Yes, as long as there is already a node there, you are correct.  Otherwise, when you create a node, the easiest way is to malloc these structures from the next pointers.

Comment: Why would you ever do that?  If you didn't already have a node, you'd want the list pointers all to be `NULL`, right?

Comment: It is the same thing to malloc a node, and then set the pointers, as it is to malloc the space from the pointers and place a node struct there.

Comment: OK, I think I see what you're getting at.  I think you're going to confuse the OP more than help him, though.

Comment: depends on your implementation.  If you memcopy a local instance of a node, its the same thing.  If you have a create node function, this is the easiest way, since that new struct is going to be wiped out with the stack frame.  Hence, you'll have ot malloc the node, and then set the pointer.